# Applying jitter to geom_hex in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some very dense data, so I would like to use geom_hex to visualize the distribution. However, they are very concentrated, such that it would dramatically help if I could jitter the underlying points.

The following works fine, but has no jitter:

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=x,y=y))+
      geom_hex()
```

I tried the following:

```
  ggplot(data=data, aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_hex(position=position_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0.1))
```

However, this produced an empty graph (labels, but not content).

Any suggestions for how to apply jitter within geom_hex is much appreciated.

Comment: If you really want to do this, you could jitter the data before with `jitter()`. Unusual to put the data inside the `aes`

Comment: include some exemple data please

Comment: Thanks, Richard. Was able to apply the jitter using jitter() (and fixed where aes() was in the example. Typing too fast writing the original...